# Rails 4.2.6 breaking have_link matcher on emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a test, that works with `rails 4.2.5.2`

```
expect(@mail.first.body.encoded).to have_link('here',
         href: edit_questionaire_url(questionaire))
```

If I upgrade to `rails 4.2.6` or `rails 4.2.7.1` then I get the following error.

```
Failure/Error:
       expect(@mail.first.body.encoded).to have_link('here',
         href: edit_questionaire_url(questionaire))

       expected to find link "here" with href "http://www.example.com/questionaires/1/edit" but there were no matches. Also found "here", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

If I compare the url in the test and the @mail.body, they are identical, apart from the quotes:

```
\"http://www.example.com/questionaires/1/edit\"  - body of email
 "http://www.example.com/questionaires/1/edit"  - test error
```

Many other similar tests are now breaking. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe the quote matters. Can you post the whole link with all attributes?

Comment: I'm guessing it also updated the `mail` gem and the encoding has changed slightly for some reason -  Have you considered using the `capybara-email` gem rather than trying to use Capybara against encoded strings?

Comment: No, I'm actually surprised it worked originally since I doubt the output of `encoded` is valid html which Capybaras have_link matcher basically requires when used with a string (parseable by Nokogiri to be exact)

Comment: That is not good news. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I followed Tom Walpole's suggestion and refactored using the [capybara-email](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/capybara-email) gem.  This had quite a few advantages, including easier to understand tests, more robust tests, and the ability to click links in emails.